# How can I open ports?

Tags: port-forwarding

I want to open a port, specifically port `32887` for `TCP`, used for Ace of Spades (buildnshoot) game.

I created a server (I can access it from `127.0.0.1`) but my friends can't join me. It looks like a port problem.

Could you guys help me?

---

EDIT:

Did everything camconn told me to do and got this out of `iptables -L` command:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:32887
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:32887 flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:32887 flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:32887 flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:32887 flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:32887 flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Is this all I have to do?

Comment: Are your friends on your Local Network (LAN)? Or are they on other networks?

Comment: Did you [follow the port forwarding guide that camconn linked to you](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/) as well for your router?  If you did not then you are not done.  If you did, then you need someone outside your network with that game to test.

Comment: Yes, I did follow it. I did everything stated [here](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/TP-Link/TL-WR541G/Ace_of_Spades.htm) but I don't know how to do that static IP thing (that guide doesn't provide linux instructions) so I edited the /etc/network/interfaces file as it tells me to do in this [site](http://www.sudo-juice.com/how-to-set-a-static-ip-in-ubuntu-the-proper-way/). My friend tested it and it didn't work...

Comment: Camconn, my friends are on other networks. Other houses or even other states

Comment: @user285672 Be sure that you point your router toward your *internal* IP address. This is usually in the form of `192.168.1.XXX` for Linksys routers. Be sure to give your friends your *external* IP address (the one people access from the internet). This is usually in the form of `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX`. You can view your *external* IP address with websites such as cmyip.com.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up *Port Forwarding* at your router. You can find instructions for your specific router [here](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/).

Specifically, you want to forward incoming traffic on port `32887` of your router to your computer's *internal* IP address (e.g. `192.168.1.XXX`) on the same port.

After you set up your router to forward traffic to your computer, simply give your friends your *external* IP address (e.g. `208.67.220.220`) and you're good to go.

**N.B. External vs. Internal IP addresses:**
Your *external* IP address is the address the outside world sees your LAN as. You can find this with a third party service such as [this](http://cmyip.com). This is the address you need to give to your friends so they can play on your server. On the other hand, your *internal* IP address is where your computer is on *your* network. Normally, an *internal* IP address is of the form `192.168.1.XXX` on Cisco/Linksys routers. You need to set up port forwarding at your *internal* IP address so that it can talk to your computer.

Extra Reading:
[What is an IP Address?](http://portforward.com/networking/whatisip.htm)
[External vs Internal IP Addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026981/are-the-terms-external-ip-address-and-public-ip-address-synonomous)

Comment: You can check if iptables is enabled on your server as well by running:
`iptables -L`

Comment: so iptables -L is the command to test if its working?

Comment: @user285672 No, `iptables -L` will only list the `iptables` rules active on your server.  It will not test if port forwarding is working.  You need to have someone outside your network attempt to connect to make sure that port forwarding is working